# Framework mixing objC-swift: unit test generated interface not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unit-testing, frameworks

I've created a framework in objC, now I'm trying to introduce some swift code inside it.
During the build process of the framework everything seems to work fine. ObjC classes can see Swift classes exposed as `public` with the @objc prefix.
What I'm not able to build are unit tests.
In the unit test I try to use the SWIFT class but the test is not able to see it, thus I'm trying to import the generated header that is different from the one of the framework, in this form
 `#import <PRODUCT_NAMETests/PRODUCT_NAMETests-Swift.h>`
Even if I do that the compiler tells me that the file was not found.
Target settings are the same for both the framework and the test.